# Use of variables in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

New to excel VBA. I know the following is incorrect as `"x" & i` will give a string, not a variable. But suppose I have 100 xs and I want to populate into cells. I do not want to put all x values in an array and later call from the array. Is there a quick and easy way to fix the following?

```
Sub test()
    x1 = 1
    x2 = 2
    x3 = 3
    For i = 1 To 3
        Cells(i, 1) = "x" & i
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `Cells(i, 1) = x & i`

Comment: Thanks. If I have "option explicit" on, I should define x the same type of variable as x1, x2, x3...? What is x exactly?

Comment: I think you should really consider telling us what you are ACTUALLY trying to do, an array will most likely make your all of your code much cleaner and faster. But if you are not interested in array you should give us more detail what you are actually trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

Re-consider using arrays:

```
Sub test()
    x = Array(1, 2, 3)
    For I = 0 To 2
        Cells(I + 1, 1) = x(I)
    Next I
End Sub
```

is easy and compact.

**EDIT:**

```
Sub test()
    x = Array(1, 2, 3)
    Range("A1:A3") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(x)
End Sub
```

is even quicker

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are aware of that but just for the OP: `For I = LBound(x) to UBound(x)`

Comment: Thanks. The reason I ask the question is because I have a situation where I need to define a series of variables named x1, x2, x3,.... with values determined earlier in the program. And later in the program I need to use these variables in an iterative fashion (in a loop). Just want to know the best way to handle multiple variables.